# jQuery UI drag and drop not working when flowplayer is included

Tags: jquery-ui, flowplayer

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/KK36F/2/

How to solve this?

Comment: Your example works in FireFox! Which browser?

Comment: For me it does not work with: Firefox 15.0.1, Chrome 22, IE 10

Comment: Hmmm, I'm using FF15.0.1 and it's fine. Have you tried CTRL+F5 to flush your js cache?

Comment: Cleared everything from cache, CTRL+F5 does not help also, asked my colleague to try it on safari, same thing. You can drag the box around?

Comment: Check it in Firebug, see if something is failing to load/blocked etc. or there's something showing up in the JavaScript console.

Comment: Asked 2 more people, nobody could get it working on any browser, very strange. No errors, warnings in console, asked in flowplayer forum, maybe developers will know what is the problem.

Comment: But does the net tab show it failing to load from the site?

Comment: No, everything loaded fine, maybe the floaplayer.min.js did not load for you and that is the reason for you to be able to drag the box, because without it drag and drop works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My old answer of:

> http://jsfiddle.net/KK36F/5/
>
> I've used jQuery noConflict to work around flowPlayer. As I can't
>   reproduce your problem (flowPlayer is blocked on my site rrrrr) it's
>   the best I can do.

Didn't work... I've managed to reproduce the problem and track it down to a line in the flowplayer code:

```
// skip IE policies
document.ondragstart = function () { return false; };
```

If you make this safer (as it is a JScript only IE thing), the draggable works again.

```
if(document.ondragstart) {
    document.ondragstart = function () { return false; };
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind waiting a few hours, I'll get to it at home, unless somebody answers it in the meantime.

Comment: See my update, reproduced and patched. I'm not using flowplayer itself so I don't know if my patch will break it. One would imagine that you could patch it with something more selective so that you don't completely break dragging.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me as well. But does that mean that drag and drop does not work in IE? Does that apply only to some IE versions, or to all?